# С клавиатуры вводятся действительные числа. Найти произведение суммы чисел с четными индексами и суммы чисел с нечетными индексами. В Си

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{

    int a , b , c, result;

        do {
        printf("Enter the number:" );
        scanf("%d", c);

        if(c % 2 != 0){
        a=a+c;
          }
       else (c % 2 == 0)
           b=b+c;
        }while(c!=0);
       result = a * b;
            printf("The product of the sum of even and odd numbers :%d", result);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `c` — вводимое число, но не индекс... И, кстати, индексы у вас по условию начинаются с нуля или с единицы?

Comment: Для начала в scanf надо %f

Comment: А неважно, с чего нумерация идёт, на результат это не влияет

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Та нет условий для индексов

Comment: @MBo Тьфу ты... а я прочел "произведения для четных и суммы для нечетных"...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Всё достаточно просто, надо отдельно суммировать числа по чётным и нечётным номерам (индексам) ввода:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{    
    int idx=1; // текущий индекс ввода
    double num, result;
    double sum_odd = 0.0;
    double sum_even = 0.0;
    int cou_nums = 5; // Количество чисел для ввода
    while(cou_nums-- > 0 ) {
        printf("Enter the number:" );
        scanf("%f", &num);

        if(idx % 2 == 0)
            sum_even += num;
        else
            sum_odd += num;
        idx++;
    }

    result = sum_odd * sum_even;
    printf("The product of the sum of even and odd numbers :%f", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: Отмечайте как решение и закрывайте вопрос

Comment: Извини но код не работает

Comment: конкретнее пожалуйста

Comment: ввожу цифру нажимаю enter и программа завершается

Comment: и не продолжает цикл

Comment: scanf("%f", &num);

Comment: Все теперь все работает( ваш ответ принял )